# Multithreaded access to an embedded HSQLDB database

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I have an HSQLDB **embedded** database, which I use to store statistics of some measurements. The statistics are expected to be arriving about every second from the same thread, but be fetched from a few different threads (from the pool of threads) every several seconds.

I do not have much experience with jdbc, so my questions may sound trivial:

1. What is the price of creating/disposing a new connection every second? Recall, that the database is embedded, so there is no TCP/IP involved.
2. What is the price of creating/disposing prepared statements every second?

Please, note that some inserts are bulk inserts, where I think to use `addBatch` and `executeBatch` methods of a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to reuse the connections and the prepared statements.

To do this, each thread will have a single connection, and each connection will reuse a set of prepared statements. The connection is committed after the unit of work is complete, but not closed. The connection is closed when your app is closed or completes its work.

You should use executeBatch for bulk inserts.

With HSQLDB, the price of creating / disposing a new connection / prepred statements every second is not high, but you should still avoid this if you can.

Comment: Do I have to implement such connection pool manually or there is something that you recommend?

Comment: Design your app to keep the Runnable class that does the work. Each instance can keep its connection and reuse it.

Comment: See the ClientThread example here: http://hsqldb.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hsqldb/base/trunk/src/org/hsqldb/test/TestBench.java?view=log

Comment: I took the apache commons-dbcp package, it seems to do exactly what I need.

Comment: Hi Fredt, i tried to dig deeper in your github example above, but could not find how (and in which file?) did you configure the multi-threading for HSQLDB. Could you share the file (with path here on SO). many thanks!

Comment: The ClientThread example url is now https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/svn/HEAD/tree/base/trunk/src/org/hsqldb/test/TestBench.java